# Practical differences between Lazy<_> and thunk (fun () -> ...)

Tags: .net, f#, lazy-loading

In the F# core library there are higher-order functions that take a thunk (`fun () -> ...`), but could also conceptually take a `Lazy<_>`, such as `Option.defaultWith`. F# has good syntactical support for `Lazy<_>` through the `lazy` keyword, but I can't think of any function in the F# core library that takes `Lazy<_>` instead of a thunk. I would guess this is because it's "more FP" to use thunks than the .NET-specific `Lazy<_>` type.

But apart from being vaguely "less FP": If the value is needed at most 1 time, what are the practical considerations of using `Lazy<_>` instead of thunks? Are there, for example, performance differences (CPU and/or allocations/memory)? Other concerns? What kind of situations are better resolved with `Lazy<_>` instead of thunks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being a separate object which wraps a thunk, provides synchronization and holds the result reference, `Lazy<_>` has some additional overhead compared to a simple thunk.

If you know you're only going to evaluate the thunk (at most) once, I don't think there's a reason why you wouldn't use a function if you can. You can wrap a call to `Lazy<_>`'s `Value` in another function, but in this case it has no benefit that I know of.

One scenario I remember where `Lazy<_>` was useful was when we had two separate feature flags in a product which both potentially required initialization of Orleankka actor system if enabled - expensive operation which should only be done once per application startup.

So our options were either a lot of nested `if`s, mutable options, or this:

```
let actorSystem = lazy initializeActorSystem ()

if feature1Enabled then
    let as = actorSystem.Value
    ...

if feature2Enabled then
    let as = actorSystem.Value
    ...
```

Unlike a thunk, `Lazy<_>` also allows you to check if the thunk was evaluated. From the same exaple:

```
if actorSystem.IsValueCreated then
    actorSystem.Value.Dispose()
```

Other cases are in general when you aren't sure you would evaluate the thunk at most once, especially if it can happen concurrently. I think we also have use case like that for reading some external configuration when not provided locally to several components that are being started concurrently - `Lazy<_>` ensures we make the remote call only once (if needed at all) regardless of which component first finds out it needs it.